# How to incorporate Golang in to your website?

Tags: django, go

I have a website that uses django and an sql database. I want to use Golang with my website i don't know any way to incorporate. I want it to accelerate my performance in the website because i have some of my "parts" (ex. Like Login and Follow its a music site) that are very cpu intensive and need to be optimized a better way. Please Help me.

Answer (score 6):

Go is a Programming Language and can be used to write the server for your web application.

This requires completely replacing django with equivalent code written in Go. You will most possibly need a web framework written on top of Go. For ex. Revel. If you want an analogy, Go is like Python. Revel is like Django.

This is a big change in your architecture. If performance is the only issue of your working website, you might want to improve the bottlenecks by just using python and django. Django and Python provide a powerful platform that can scale your application to a practically large number of users.

There is also ways that you can change only small parts of your infrastructure by incorporating Go. Look for micro-services architecture in order to think on those lines.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the answer :)